# Magento single sign on from different servers

Tags: api, session, cookie

I have Magento running on one server and I would like to check from a different server, same domain, different subdomain, whether a customer is logged in. Basically customers log in to Magento and once I know they are logged in I would like to allow them to automatically log in to the site on my other server where I am not using php. Is there a way after I retrieve the Magento cookie to then ask Magento, using the API perhaps, whether the session is valid and the customer is currently logged in?

Thank you in advance for your time.

Comment: I don't recall anything in the API that would allow for that, but this website claims to support Magento as a SAML service provider. This would allow you to use Magento to authenticate from whatever other website you have, almost everything has methods for SAML authentication through libraries.

http://www.ssoeasy.com/blog/post/Magento-SAML-20-SP-Service-Provider-Single-Sign-On-SSO.aspx

Comment: @user5261. Thanks for what? What did I say?

Comment: @user5261 did you ever get anywhere with this?

Comment: @user5261: I'm curious to see if you got any further development on this as well. Any update?